# Firebase Hosting Automatically Adds Target _blank to Absolute URLs Links

Tags: html, firebase, hyperlink, href, firebase-hosting

Out of no where, Firebase Hosting started automatically adding `target="\_blank"` to all links that are absolute URLs. If I use relative blanks, I does not add the target attribute.

I have nothing in the `firebase.json` file that could cause this, nor can I find any setting in the Firebase Console.

Note: I am uploading static HTML files using the Firebase CLI -- the static file(s) DO-NOT have the `target="\_blank"` what so ever.

**Example to replicate:**

```html
<! -- In the static file -->
<a href="https://somesite.com/to-a-link/">link</a>

<! -- Firebase changes to: -->
<a href="https://somesite.com/to-a-link/" target="_blank" rel="noopener">link</a>

<! -- If I use the same link as relative: -->
<a href="/to-a-link/">link</a>

<! -- Firebase Hosting implements no change to the link attributes: -->
<a href="/to-a-link/">link</a>
```

I'm assuming there is a setting in the console I need to change but where??

Thnx for the input ahead of time.